# Created Facebook Application Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried to follow the sample tutorial of facebook : developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#debug

But after i made it and clicked on cook button , it is showing "Error Occured".

You can see the app here : http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html

The following is the page source for the app:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# og_recipebox: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/abcrecipelist#"> 
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="258611890922127" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="abcrecipelist:recipe" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="Oreo Stuffed Cookies" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-92sA7pC51pg/T9CKdHHeDzI/AAAAAAAACbg/MRq4PR2P5QQ/s1600/jQuery_Cookies.jpg" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function postCook()
    {
        FB.api('/me/abcrecipelist:cook&recipe=http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html','post',  function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ 
            appId:'258611890922127', cookie:true, 
                    status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true
        });
        </script>
        <fb:add-to-timeline></fb:add-to-timeline>>
        <h3>
            <font size="30" face="verdana" color="grey">Stuffed Cookies
            </font> 
        </h3> 
        <p>
            <img title="Oreo Stuffed Cookies" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-92sA7pC51pg/T9CKdHHeDzI/AAAAAAAACbg/MRq4PR2P5QQ/s1600/jQuery_Cookies.jpg" width="550"/><br />
        </p>       

        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
        </form>

        <fb:activity actions="YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook"></fb:activity>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Also here is the screenshot from basic settings of the app :

[image]

Please tell me whats wrong..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Log the value of `response` to your browser’s console and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call is incorrect:

```
FB.api('/me/abcrecipelist:cook&recipe=http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html' ...
```

Should be

```
FB.api('/me/abcrecipelist:cook?recipe=http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html' ...
```

I.e. The *&* should be a *?*.

Comment: Thanks for the help..  I have fixed it my self by changing the api into   : --- FB.api(
        '/me/abcrecipelist:cook',
        'post',
        { recipe: 'http://www.akashbc.com/facebookapp/index.html' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });